# Ecslidingviewcontroller and Uislider

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have a problem with the [Ecslidingviewcontroller](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) project, if I insert an Uislider into the view I can't touch it nice because the sliding motion of the sliders is being mistaken as a swipe left/right.
This is the code on the viewWillApper:

```
    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
  }

  if (![self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController isKindOfClass:[UnderRightViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UnderRight"];
  }

  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

Is there a way to disable the view effect on the sliders?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**move gesture recogniser to navigation bar**

```
[_navBarOutlet addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

**or remove this line**

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

and add this

```
self.slidingViewController.shouldAddPanGestureRecognizerToTopViewSnapshot = YES;
```